# How to close user session/auth. context after access token is sent for a user/client in Spring OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing an app, let's call it *OAuth2Client*, whose authentication/authorization layer is managed with the spring OAuth2 protocol implementation on a different server, *OAuth2Server*.
Everything is working great so far, I just want to divert a little bit from the "normal" OAuth2 flow.

So for example, in my third party app *OAuth2Client*, when users wants to log in, they have to authenticate via *OAuth2Server*.
We then have the familiar OAuth2 flow where the user is redirected to the authentication page of the *OAuth2Server*, enters credentials, is asked for the permission to access his/her data etc.

If authentication is successful, he is redirected to the 'redirect_uri' registered with the *OAuth2Client* app, with the auth. 'code' included in the request. *OAuth2Client* then exchanges this 'code' with an 'access token' via an api call to the access token endpoint on the *OAuth2Server*.

What I want to do is **close the user session/authentication context immediately** after the user has successfully authenticated and has been provided with an access token.

I thought of using a filter to do that but I am not sure whether that's the best solution.

Any help would be appreciated
thanks in advance...

Comment: On which server you want to do this (oauth2 server or client server) ? and tell me why you want to do this ?

Comment: @prtk_shah I would like to do this on the server and the reason why I want to do it is because after the access token is sent, there is no need for the user to have his session opened on the oauth2 server anymore.

Comment: I think Dave's solution will do the needed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can attach the session event to the /token endpoint, but the session is actually not needed any more after the user has approved the grant and the authorization code is issued. So this would work:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
public class ApprovalEndpoint {

  @RequestMapping("/oauth/confirm_access")
  public ModelAndView getAccessConfirmation(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, SessionStatus status) throws Exception {
    String template = createTemplate(model, request);
    if (request.getAttribute("_csrf") != null) {
      model.put("_csrf", request.getAttribute("_csrf"));
    }
    status.setComplete();
    return new ModelAndView(new SpelView(template), model);
  }

}
```

Or you could use a `Filter` as you suggest, but since you probably want to customize the user experience for approval anyway, you might as well do it via this endpoint.

Comment: one little issue with this is that the /oauth/confirm_access is already mapped to the framework access confirmation endpoint. I have tried using an Interceptor but I couldn't clear neither the SecurityContextHolder authentication (by nulling it) nor the context. But I guess what I am attempting to do is kind of against the principle of single sign-on so maybe it is better if I leave it for now. Thanks for the tips anyway.

Comment: It's not against any kind of principle at all. If you write the "/oauth/confirm_access" as I suggested it (by design) overrides the framework endpoint - that's how you provide a custom UI for approval. Did you try it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

My oauth clients are set to  autoApprove(true) , so I cannot do as Dave says. 
My solution is mapping /oauth/authorize to another endpoint ,and inject the origin AuthorizationEndpoint, after origin Endpoint finish his work, call request.getSession().invalidate();

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.util.OAuth2Utils;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
@SessionAttributes({SessionClosedAuthorizationEndpoint.AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_ATTR_NAME, SessionClosedAuthorizationEndpoint.ORIGINAL_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_ATTR_NAME})
public class SessionClosedAuthorizationEndpoint  {
    private AuthorizationEndpoint authorizationEndpoint;
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthorizationEndpoint(AuthorizationEndpoint authorizationEndpoint) {
        this.authorizationEndpoint = authorizationEndpoint;
    }

    static final String AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_ATTR_NAME = "authorizationRequest";

    static final String ORIGINAL_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_ATTR_NAME = "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.ORIGINAL_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST";


    @RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/authorize/custom")
    public ModelAndView authorize(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters, SessionStatus sessionStatus, Principal principal) {
        ModelAndView authorize = authorizationEndpoint.authorize(model, parameters, sessionStatus, principal);
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        return authorize;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/authorize/custom", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = OAuth2Utils.USER_OAUTH_APPROVAL)
    public View approveOrDeny(@RequestParam Map<String, String> approvalParameters, Map<String, ?> model,
                              SessionStatus sessionStatus, Principal principal){
        return authorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(approvalParameters,model,sessionStatus,principal);
    }

}
```